# Ordering a specific post type

Tags: customization

I'm trying to figure out how to order my posts by a custom field. I'm using a calendar (The events calendar), with a custom field called 'artist'. It works, though my query request affects all other post types as well which causes my menu and news items to disappear. Here's the code I have right now:

```
function order_calendar_by_artist( $query ){
   $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artist' );
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );  

   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_calendar_by_artist', 99 );
```

If I set the post_type as well, I also get a 404 error on my homepage:

```
function order_calendar_by_artist( $query ){
   $query->set( 'post_type', 'tribe_events' );
   $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artist' );
   $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );  

   return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_calendar_by_artist', 99 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I've found the solution, by first filtering with `is_main_query()`, and then using the `is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' )` conditional statement as was proposed in the first answer.

```
function order_calendar_by_artist( $query ){    

   if ( is_admin() ||  !$query->is_main_query() ) {
      return;
   }

   if( is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) ){
      $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artist' );
      $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
   } 

}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_calendar_by_artist', 99 );
```

**Old Answer 2**

Try the following (found on the plugin forum):

```
function order_calendar_by_artist( $query ) {
    if ( !empty( $query->tribe_is_multi_posttype ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artist' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_calendar_by_artist' );
```

It appears you need to find the correct `$query` for the calendar plugin. You could always `print_r( $query);` to see which queries are running on that page and adjust the conditional accordingly. Might take a while but it's all I can think of at the mo.

---

**Old answer 1**

You could wrap the function code inside a conditional statement like so:

```
function order_calendar_by_artist( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'artist' );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
    }

    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_calendar_by_artist', 99 );
```

What that should do is only adjust the query on the `tribe_events` post type archive page. The conditional may need adjusting dependent on where the query needs to take affect. At the moment you're using the `pre_get_posts` action which is affecting every single query on the site so you'll need to hone into a specific area in which you want your function to run (i.e. using a conditional).

You can also use the following to avoid affecting the admin side

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tribe_events' ) && !is_admin() ) {
    ...
}
```

I've not actually tested this however it should work... (he says)

Failing that you might need to utilise the `WP_Query()` function and create a new query wherever you need to re-order your posts.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'     => 'ASC', //or DESC
    'meta_key'  => 'artist'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        //Loop stuff
    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've tried `is_post_type_archive`, but it is not working unfortunately. I've also tried using `get_post_type($post->ID) == 'tribe_events'` but all these conditionals seem to get ignored.

Since i'm trying to do this via my functions.php file, where do I put your last code snippet in my WP installation?

Comment: Hi Tom. You'd need to add this in the template in which the query is being performed. Is it part of a plugin or the theme?

Comment: It is part of "The Events Calendar" plugin

Comment: Updated answer although it's still not absolute I'm afraid.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the solution! Thanks for helping